# Dynamically select items for next listbox on select of previous listbox in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, fetch, drop-down-menu

I have three select boxes :- `select1` `select2` `select3`, i am fetching data from mysql database for `select1`, Now on the basis of the select of `select1` i want to fetch the listitem from mysql database, and on the select of `select3` i want to fetch the list as per the selection of `select2`.

How i can do that?

Comment: Any simple ajax tutorial should cover this.

Comment: please if you could get me path, i was searching could not able to find, so asked here.

Comment: pick one: https://www.google.com/?q=ajax%20select%20box or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+select+box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link the can do the trick.... Waited for long for answers, but could not able to get. Finally its here and working great.

http://www.dougv.com/2009/04/24/using-ajax-to-data-bind-a-child-drop-down-list-based-on-the-selected-option-of-a-parent-select-control/